# How to always start website

Tags: asp.net, iis

How to always start website?

because I run a thread in background and want to run always.but when nobody login to site,thread doesn't run

I find [this link](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Oct/02/Use-IIS-Application-Initialization-for-keeping-ASPNET-Apps-alive) but doesn't help me

Comment: Its hard to understand the actual problem associated with your question? All the answers here, have iterated more or less the same things mentioned in the article you've linked to! By the way, I hope you are using IIS 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a background thread application is not a good idea if your website is having high traffic. I suggest you to create windows service which will run on a regular time interval. But still if you want to run then you can choose make your application pool to always running like following(IIS 7.5 and high version).

```
<applicationPools> 
  <add name="MyAppWorkerProcess" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" startMode="AlwaysRunning" /> 
</applicationPools>
```

For more details see following link.

http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2009/10/11/iis-7-5-and-always-running-web-applications.aspx

Comment: please delete your answer that i delete this question